# DD() prints value but return statement 'non-object'

Tags: laravel, datatables

I am using data tables for package for Laravel API

```
->addColumn('zoomname', function(time_tables $time_tables) {
 return $time_tables->zoom->zoom_name;
})


public function zoom(): BelongsTo 
{
return $this->belongsTo(zoomapi::class, 'zoom_id');
}
```

in there can't return foreign value
when I return foreign value its says

`"error": "Exception Message:\n\nTrying to get property 'zoomname' of non-object"`

like below image
[image]

then I used dd() function it working properly

```
->addColumn('zoomname', function(time_tables $time_tables) {
dd($time_tables->zoom->zoom_name)
     return $time_tables->zoom->zoom name;
    })
```

[image]

when I use  `dump($time_tables->zoom->zoomname)`
[image]

any one can you help me???

Comment: `dd` is ending the execution and this is most likely doing something to multiple records so you are just killing it before it gets to the offending 'record'

Comment: `dump(..)` also look like this

Comment: Try `return $time_tables->zoom ? $time_tables->zoom->zoomname : 'no zoom';`

Comment: right .. because the second 'record' is the one that doesn't have that relationship (returns `null`) for `zoom`

Comment: @lagbox yes thank you ❤️❤️❤️

Comment: @lagbox can you answer this question?

Comment: please provide code instead of screenshots